# How the variable values are changing while using conditional operator?

Tags: c, pointers, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

Can anyone help me to Explain the output of the the Above code..
it will printing different output in different compilers. Which
one to be considered.

## Code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=0, b=1, c=2;
    *((a+1 == 1) ? &b : &a) = a ? b : c;
    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

## Output

```
0,2,2
```

<sub>This output is from Codeblocks</sub>

Comment: Which compiler(s) gave a different output?

Answer (score 6):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
int* ptr;

if (a + 1 == 1)   // which is true
{
    ptr = &b;     // So ptr points to b
}
else
{
    ptr = &a;
}

if (a != 0)       // which is false
{
    *ptr = b;    
}
else
{
    *ptr = c;      // so *ptr (which is same as b) is set equal to c
}
```

So what happens is `b=c;`

Answer (score 4):

The line in your code

```
   *((a+1 == 1) ? &b : &a) = a ? b : c;
```

uses [conditional operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) (or, ternary operator) `?:`. As per the properties, quoting from `C11`, chapter §6.5.15,

> The first operand is evaluated; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and the
>   evaluation of the second or third operand (whichever is evaluated). The second operand
>   is evaluated only if the first compares unequal to 0; the third operand is evaluated only if
>   the first compares equal to 0; the result is the value of the second or third operand
>   (whichever is evaluated), converted to the type described below [...]

So, for LHS,

```
 *((a+1 == 1) ? &b : &a)
```

`a` is 0, so `(a+1 == 1)` is true (1), so it reduces to `*(&b)` (second operand).

For the RHS,

```
     a ? b : c;
```

`a` being 0, it reduces to `c`, (third operand).

So, taken together, it is

```
 *(&b) = c;
```

or

```
  b = c;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a=0, b=1, c=2;
*((a+1 == 1) ? &b : &a) = a ? b : c;
printf("%d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c);
```

a+1 -> 0+1 -> 1 == 1 True, therefore *(&b)
Now, a = 0 false, therefore c.

Now equating *(&b) = c which is b = c , a and c don't change.

```
a ? b : c
```

is same as :

```
  if(a)
        b;
    else
        c;
```